# Error during File Management in Assembly

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to write a simple code in assembly `(NASM 2, Linux)` for creating a text file and writing something into it. But on running the below code I found that file name is not as I have mentioned in the code it is concatenated with the content of the file. i.e.

It generates a file named `file.txtHello World` where `Hello World` is the content of the file.

```
section .data
    file_name db 'file.txt'

    msg       db 'Hello World', 0xa
    len equ $-msg

section .bss
    fd_out resb 1

section .text
    global _start           ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point

    ;Create the file
    mov ebx, file_name
    mov ecx, 777            ;(read write execute = 111 = 7) by all (owner, group, and others)
    mov eax, 8              ;system call number (sys_creat)
    int 0x80                ;call kernel
    mov [fd_out], byte eax

    ;Write into the file
    mov ebx, [fd_out]       ;file descriptor 
    mov ecx, msg            ;message to write
    mov edx, len            ;number of bytes
    mov eax, 4              ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80                ;call kernel

    ;Close the file
    mov eax, 6              ;system call number (sys_close)
    int 0x80                ;call kernel

    mov eax,1               ;System call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80                ;Call kernel
```

I do not have any idea, Why is that happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filename must be zero-ended :

```
file_name db 'file.txt',0
```